# Get rowid from listview for deleting the row in the database

Tags: android

I am using Custom Adapter to populate a listview which is reading from the database.Here when i do a longpress on a listitem,i want to delete the item from the listview and the database.How to get the rowid to delete that item from the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass that id to custom list adapter and make method returning the id which will get called onItemclick and this id you can pass to db to delete the corresponding row and then you can update the list..

Comment: I am new to android,can u give some code snippets to understand better if u have.Thanks

Comment: for custom list adapter: http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/custom-list-adapter.html, initialize id values in the constructor and by creating a mehtod you can return its value over position argument..

Comment: I am using the same adapter for some other activities also.if i change the parameters of constructor,it may affect my other activities.Do you have any idea about adapter.getItemId(position).

Comment: mAdapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, mTitle, mFavProgDesc, mFavProgIcons , mIcon); mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) { mFavouritesDb.deleteFavourite(????????)); } }) return false; }   This is my code.

Comment: mRowId = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FavouritesDatabase.ROWID)); mAdapter.setRowId(mRowId); Inside OnItemClick         mFavouritesDb.deleteFavourite(mAdapter.getRowId());      
} I have added getter and setter methods in Adapter class.But showing nullpointer exception in this line.Can u tell where i am doin wrong

Comment: Thanks i have deleted successfully from the database.But i want to update my listview with new values,Can u help in this?

Comment: update values in variable and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged()..You should accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Do i have to delete the item from the list and then call noti.. method.If yes how to delete item from the list

Comment: Yes,I have done by using remove(info.position) of array and called invalidateViews() method.Thanks for all